# How to run a loop in the background while running other code in python

Tags: python, 2048

I have a python script that (somewhat) plays 2048. The way it works is it presses left, detects if there has been a change or not, and if there hasn't (AKA the move didn't work) it presses up, if that doesn't work it presses down, etc.. If there had been a change it moves on to the next move.

At the same time, I want it to constantly be checking if the user is pressing `esc`, and if they are, end the program. This way you can end it at any time.

Here's the code that checks for `esc`:

```
while True:
    if keyboard.read_key() == "esc":
        endofgame = True
        break
```

And here's the code that does the moving:

```
while not endofgame:
    endgameim = grab()
    pxcolour = endgameim.getpixel((818,453))
    print(pxcolour)
    if pxcolour == (123, 110, 101):
        endofgame = True
        print(endofgame)
        break
    while True:
        im = grab()
        pyautogui.press("left")
        im2 = grab()
        diff = ImageChops.difference(im2, im)
        bbox = diff.getbbox()
        print(bbox)
        if bbox is not None:
            continue
        else:
            pyautogui.press("up")
            im2 = grab()
            diff = ImageChops.difference(im2, im)
            bbox = diff.getbbox()
            if bbox is not None:
                continue
            else:
                pyautogui.press("down")
                im2 = grab()
                diff = ImageChops.difference(im2, im)
                bbox = diff.getbbox()
                if bbox is not None:
                    continue
                else:
                    pyautogui.press("right")
                    continue
                    break
            break
    break
```

By the way, I know I could do this more simply by just scraping the code from the site, but I wanted to challenge myself and do it almost purely by images.

Comment: you should run all in one loop.

Comment: instead of `if bbox is not None: continue else: ...` you could do `if bbox is None: ...` without `continue`

Comment: @furas actually, I originally had this. It doesn't work for some reason, and when I did it the long way, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just add your condition in the beginning of the while loop and it will loop with th rest of the code.

```
while not endofgame:
    if keyboard.read_key() == "esc":
        endofgame = True
        break
    endgameim = grab()
    pxcolour = endgameim.getpixel((818,453))
    print(pxcolour)
    if pxcolour == (123, 110, 101):
        endofgame = True
        print(endofgame)
        break
    while True:
        im = grab()
        pyautogui.press("left")
        im2 = grab()
        diff = ImageChops.difference(im2, im)
        bbox = diff.getbbox()
        print(bbox)
        if bbox is not None:
            continue
        else:
            pyautogui.press("up")
            im2 = grab()
            diff = ImageChops.difference(im2, im)
            bbox = diff.getbbox()
            if bbox is not None:
                continue
            else:
                pyautogui.press("down")
                im2 = grab()
                diff = ImageChops.difference(im2, im)
                bbox = diff.getbbox()
                if bbox is not None:
                    continue
                else:
                    pyautogui.press("right")
                    continue
                    break
            break
    break
```

Comment: This doesn't work - I think it's because FIRSTLY it detects if I press ```esc```, and then if I don't press it at that very millisecond it moves onto the rest of the code. Therefore I have to press ```esc``` right at the very millisecond before it makes its move, which is next to impossible. I could be wrong though. Either way, it doesn't work.